# How can I explore Body Labs' Blue with my API key before embedding into our production-level site?

Tags: html, bodylabs

I would like to use my API key to begin prototyping with Blue but before embedding it into our production-level site. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to sample Blue before embedding is actually to make a practice HTML page on a local machine.

Embed Blue into a simple HTML page, make sure that your origin account settings also include localhost, and use http-server (or similar) to run on your localhost (http-server -a localhost) . You can then explore with Blue from your local machine by opening that HTML file from your browser (most likely the url will be localhost:8080 - it will tell you when you run the http-server what port to use it on).

Just be sure to remove localhost from your account settings before using your app in production!

Be sure to check out the documentation for more information: http://developer.bodylabs.com/blue_reference.html